# glmer interpretation with a Poisson distribution

Tags: mixed-model

I ran an experiment measuring species richness and oyster abundance inside and outside seven different ponds all within the same geographic area (~1km)

I am using oyster abundance (in percents 0-100) and species richness (discrete) as response variables, location (inside vs. outside) as independent variables and pond #'s 1-7 as a random effect.

I'm having trouble interpreting the results here's what my summary table looks like:

[image]

So from what I understand, species richness is significantly different between inside and outside the ponds
Is there any more information I can gain from this? 
Any follow up post-hoc tests I should run?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of points:

- Is richness a count variable? It was not clear from your description. If it is, then you should also investigate whether you have any over-dispersion by fitting a negative binomial mixed model. With regard oyster abundance perhaps a binomial distribution would be more appropriate or a Beta distribution if it is really a continuous outcome in the $(0, 1)$ interval.
- The coefficient for `locationout` is the difference in the log expected counts of richness between the outside and inside
- Since `location` only has two levels, you do not need to run any post-hoc tests.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for your incredibly helpful insight! 
Richness is a count variable, sorry for not making that clear in my initial question. I'm a novice when it comes to stats and really appreciate you helping me out. With that said,